# Fuzzyfication of an excel file using ranges from a txt with simpful

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

I want to fuzzyficate this excel file using simpful:
[image]

with these fuzzy rules:

[image]

In this case, for example, I'd need the excel to be 'FIFTIES' if the age is between 50 and 59 and EVOL to be '10to15' if EVOL is between 10 and 15 and so on. Like this:
[image]

Only the Numerical variables need to change, the categorical ones always stay the same.

I'm pretty new with the simpful library so any help is welcome, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm Marco Nobile, one of Simpful's developers. Sorry for the late reply, I'm afraid we missed this post.

It is not entirely clear to me what you wish to implement. If you want to create linguistic variables and some specific fuzzy sets, you can use something along these lines:

```
from simpful import *
FR = FuzzySystem()
fuzzy_set_twenties = TriangleFuzzySet(28,28,32, term="twenties")
fuzzy_set_thirties = TrapezoidFuzzySet(28,32,38,42, term="thirties") 
age = LinguisticVariable([fuzzy_set_twenties, fuzzy_set_thirties], universe_of_discourse=[25,90])
FR.add_linguistic_variable("Age", age)
FR.produce_figure()
```

which should give you this

[image]

I hope this helps! Else, feel free to send me an e-mail.